# Concise way of creating Guava's Optional based on String being empty or not

Tags: java, string, guava, option-type

I'm using Guava's `Optional` and I want to return `Optional.absent()` when string is empty or `Optional.of(name)` when string is not empty. Can I do it in some concise form without using ternary operator? Here's my current code:

```
final String name = getName();
final Optional<String> optional;
if (name.isEmpty()) {
    optional = Optional.absent();
} else {
    optional = Optional.of(name);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
Optional<String> optional = Optional.fromNullable(Strings.emptyToNull(name));
```

[Guava emptyToNull](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#emptyToNull-java.lang.String-)

[Guava fromNullable](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#fromNullable-T-)